# explode pandas data frame column of object type to string and into different rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a data frame that is built like this :

```
    data = {'name':["['jem','nate','dory']", "['dave','roshy','nomy','pika']", "['kosh','liam']"], 'depart' : ['a','b','c']}

    name                               depart
0   ['jem','nate','dory']              a
1   ['dave','roshy','nomy','pika']     b
2   ['kosh','liam']                    c
```

I want to explode this into something like this

```
name    depart
jem     a
nate    a
dory    a
dave    b
roshy   b
normy   b
pika    b
kosh    c
liam    c
```

TIA for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `pd.eval()`:

```
df['name']=pd.eval(df['name'])
df=df.explode('name',ignore_index=True)
```

**OR**

```
from ast import literal_eval


df['name']=df['name'].map(literal_eval)
df=df.explode('name',ignore_index=True)
```

Now If you print `df` you will get desired output